# Remove Dash/Hyphen From Wordpress CustomPosttype Permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I want to remove all hyphens/dashes from the custom post type permalink in Wordpress.

For example:

www.website.com/customposttype/**post-name**/

Becomes :

www.website.com/customposttype/**postname**/

I want automatic solution for future and old posts.

Any advice on how to do this with any functions.

Thanks

Comment: You want automatic solution for future and old posts? If it is just not many posts, you can easily manually edit the slugs, remove spaces so no dashes...

Comment: i want automatic solution for future and old posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use to hook into WordPress's sanitize title hook.

```
function no_dashes($title) {
    return str_replace('-', '', $title);
}
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'no_dashes' , 9999);
```

It will remove the dashes from the URL. However it will work only when you save a post. That is for new posts it will work just fine. But for existing posts, you have to go and edit/hit update/save to make it happen.

TODO: Also you need to have to check for Custom Post Type also, so it does not apply for all post types.

UPDATE: I thought adding post_type check would be easier hence I added above TODO, but you are right looks like we do not have any data related to that on the filter hook I used.

For that please use this code and see if it works:

```
function no_dashes( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type ) {

    if( $post_type == "page" ) {
        $slug = str_replace( '-', '', $slug);
    }
    return $slug;
}
add_filter( "wp_unique_post_slug", "no_dashes", 10, 4 );
```

Comment: its working for all post,page and custom post type i want to remove dash from only in custom post type how to do that

Comment: @sarun Check updated code and see if it works for you.

Comment: @sarun Great! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Warning, dashes and hyphens must only be removed in utl path, not in domain.
That's why I would do something like this :

Something like this :

```
// This is our sample url, I just add a hyphen in domain name to ensure it won't be replaced
$url = "http://www.my-website.com/customposttype/post-name/foo_bar/";

// We use native php url parser to extract url path
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
$url_path = $parsed_url["path"];

// Then, we replace dashes and hyphens in this path using a simple regular expression
$url_path = preg_replace('/(-|_)/', '', $url_path);

// Finally we rebuild a new url from the original one by replacing the path with the new one
$new_url = $parsed_url["scheme"].$parsed_url["host"].$url_path;
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/HNgS/1)

Comment: Removing just dashes on php level is going to break all WP links of those posts if it is not done on WP level ...